# How can I check email template variable empty or not in mail template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend, email-templates, email-translation

I want to check the mail template variable is empty or not in my custom mail template
I do follow code in that

```
{if $data.nature_of_business != ''}}
    <li><strong>{{trans "Nature of Business:"}}</strong> 
    {{trans "%nature_of_business" nature_of_business=$data.nature_of_business}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

But that is not working for me.

Comment: I think you can try ` {{depend $data.nature_of_business}} Some code {{/depend}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this below code. You missed one opening brace :

```
{{if data.nature_of_business != ''}}
    <li><strong>{{trans "Nature of Business:"}}</strong> 
    {{trans "%nature_of_business" nature_of_business=data.nature_of_business}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

or

```
{{if data.nature_of_business}}
    <li><strong>{{trans "Nature of Business:"}}</strong> 
    {{trans "%nature_of_business" nature_of_business=data.nature_of_business}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: right condition  working for me is  {{if data.nature_of_business}}